# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que se agregue otros datos automáticamente después de que el usuario haya ingresado cierto número (en python)?

Tags: python

Lo que pasa es que estoy haciendo un gestor de tareas escolares y no se cómo hacer eso, por ejemplo después de que el usuario ingrese el número de materias quiero que aparezca esa cantidad de espacios con lo siguiente:
materia1 = input ("Ingrese la primera materia": )

Y así sucesivamente hasta cumplir el número digitado.
Psdt: Soy nuevo en la programación.

Solo eh echo esto:

num_mater = int(input (¿Cuántas materias desea ingresar?: ))

Comment: Lo que necesitas es crear una lista y añadir las materia por medio de un bucle for.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] Por favor haz el [tour] y consulta [ask]. Si estás interesado en [tag:python] sería bueno que leas su documentación. Un buen sitio para empezar es [tutorial de python](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/index.html)

Comment: Hola! ¿Que es lo que quieres añadir exactamente?

Comment: Quiero por ejemplo, si el usuario pone la cantidad de materias 8, se agreguen 8 espacios que diga por ejemplo: Ingresé la primera materia, luego Ingresé la segunda materia....y así sucesivamente hasta el 8.